# Formally evaluating integral to calculate electric or gravitational field.

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

I never understood how such integrals are calculated, formally. In a line is easy, just a line integral. In a surface, sometimes is easy, like in a disc. But, some surfaces, like sphere, it gets harder. Volumes is even harder.

Let's say I want to calculate the electric field in a generic point $\vec r = (x, y, z)$. There was a uniformly charged volume, with density charge $\rho$.

Formally, I have to give the parametrization of my volume. Let's consider this one:
$$
\gamma(r, \theta, \phi) = r(\cos\theta \sin\phi, \sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\theta)
$$

If $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$ and $0\le\phi\le\pi$ and $0\le r \le R$, then $\gamma$ is a ball of radius $R$. If $S(\theta, \phi) = \gamma(R, \theta, \phi)$, then $S$ is a sphere of radius $R$.

But, let's consider the following parametrization:
$$
\begin{array}{}
    0\le\theta\le 2\pi  \\
    0\le\phi\le\pi  \\
    a\le r \le b
\end{array}
$$

For a point $\vec r$, the electric field $d\vec E$ is:
$$
d\vec E = \frac{k dq}{|\vec\gamma - \vec r|^2}
$$

Where $k$ is just a constant depending on the nature: if is electric, or gravitational. Then, the electric field:
$$
\vec E(\vec r) = 
\iiint_\gamma\frac{k\rho}{|\vec\gamma - \vec r|^2}dv = 
\int_a^b\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{k\rho}{|\vec\gamma - \vec r|^2} r^2\sin\phi \text{ } d\theta d\phi dr
$$

This is a so bad integral to evaluate. How to figure out the result, but keeping formal? Is there a quicker way (keeping formal of course)?

Comment: Do you know how to find the electric field if the charged volume is a ball?

Comment: @JiK. Formally, no. The integral is the same, but one thing: $a=0$ and $b=R$. So, same integral.

Comment: You can write $\int_a^b f(r) dr = \int_0^b f(r) dr - \int_0^a f(r) dr$, where $f$ is the result after integrating away the angular coordinates. Then both of the integrals on the right are integrals over balls, which can be determined by a symmetry argument as you've probably seen before.

Comment: @Ian. Yes, but I still have to solve $\int f(r)dr$ first. And, how to make the symmetry argument formal?